# How to Select all Category with its specific Parent CategoryName

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working on an application. where I have a Table:-

```
Category(Category_ID,CategoryName,Parent,Category_Tag)
```

In this table Category_ID and Parent of type bigint and CategoryName and Category_Tag are of nvarchar. I want to select all CategoryName from Category table with its Name and Parent Name also. If any Category does not have any Parent then the query should return '-'

I have used following sql query:

```
SELECT Category_ID, Category_Name, Parent, Category_Tag FROM Category
```

But dows not getting the desired result.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only ONE level parent category then use LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT a.Category_ID, a.Category_Name, a.Parent, a.Category_Tag,
       ISNULL(b.Category_Name,'-') as Parent_Name
FROM Category as a
LEFT JOIN Category as b on (a.Parent=b.Category_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the empty parent to be replaced with '-', use ISNULL

```
SELECT Category_ID, Category_Name, ISNULL(convert(varchar(20),Parent), '-') as Parent, Category_Tag FROM Category
```